# vnc without internet connection

Tags: networking, vnc

I want to set up a VNC connection between my computer and my mobile phone.
I created a Wi-Fi hotspot on the computer and I connected my phone to this Wi-Fi network.
I set up a VNC server on the computer, using `tigervnc`.
I checked and it is running:

```
_$ sudo systemctl status vncserver@1.service
● vncserver@1.service - Remote desktop service (VNC)
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/vncserver@.service; enabled; vendor prese
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2019-08-07 18:27:15 CEST; 2h 41min ago
 Main PID: 10463 (vncserver)
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 904.0K
   CGroup: /system.slice/system-vncserver.slice/vncserver@1.service
       ‣ 10463 /usr/bin/perl /usr/bin/vncserver :1 -geometry 1440x900 -alway_
```

I also checked port 5901:

```
_$ nmap localhost
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-08-07 18:43 CEST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00049s latency).
Not shown: 998 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
631/tcp  open  ipp
5901/tcp open  vnc-1_
```

On the mobile phone I installed a VNC client. I did not set up ssh.
I tried to connect it to the server with the address `localhost:5901`.
But to no avail; I see this message:

"The port on which the computer is listening for a connection could not be contacted."

I have no idea why I can't connect. The Ubuntu server does not run a firewall.

This is the outcome of "sudo iptables-save"

```
$ sudo iptables-save  
 # Generated by iptables-save v1.6.1 on Wed Aug  7 22:52:46 2019  
*filter  
:INPUT ACCEPT [6569:5209874]  
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]  
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [5441:510108]  
-A INPUT -i wlp3s0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT  
-A INPUT -i wlp3s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT  
-A INPUT -i wlp3s0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT  
-A INPUT -i wlp3s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT  
-A FORWARD -d 10.42.0.0/24 -o wlp3s0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT  
-A FORWARD -s 10.42.0.0/24 -i wlp3s0 -j ACCEPT  
-A FORWARD -i wlp3s0 -o wlp3s0 -j ACCEPT  
-A FORWARD -o wlp3s0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable  
-A FORWARD -i wlp3s0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable  
COMMIT  
 # Completed on Wed Aug  7 22:52:46 2019  
 # Generated by iptables-save v1.6.1 on Wed Aug  7 22:52:46 2019  
*nat  
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [215:28223]  
:INPUT ACCEPT [160:24399]  
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [677:49578]  
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [643:47493]  
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.42.0.0/24 ! -d 10.42.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE  
COMMIT  
 # Completed on Wed Aug  7 22:52:46 2019
```

Comment: Did you connect with `localhost:5001` on your phone or on the computer?

Comment: The vnc server is installed on the Ubuntu computer. The VNC client is on the phone; The vnc-client asks the address of VNC-server I want to connect to. So I typed "localhost:5901" on the phone.

Comment: For the VNC client, what did you put for the server address?

Comment: VNC client:  localhost:5901

Comment: Can you add the output of `sudo fuser 5901/tcp` and `sudo iptables-save`?

Comment: $ sudo fuser 5901/tcp
5901/tcp:              971

Comment: sudo iptables-save  : to many characters to put as a comment.  I'l put the outcome as an "edit" to my question.

Comment: @peter, instead of responding with Add Comment, please update the question with [edit] as you see I did for you above.

Comment: @NerdOfLinux Q edited with more info that you might have missed.

Answer (score 2):

On the phone, you need to input the interface address on the computer, that you want to connect to. So this is the WiFi interface (the thing creating the wireless connection) on the PC, to which the phone needs to connect to.

So, on your PC run the command:

```
    ip addr
```

and look for your WiFi interface name. This could be your WiFi card or USB WiFi dongle, and the name could be something like "wlx503eaa2592a3".

Now, along with that interface name, there should be an ip address. It will be preceded by the word "inet" and might be something like 192.168.42.186 (this is an example of a private IP address). This is a IPv4 address.

If your interface does not have a IPv4 IP address, then you need to go to network settings and set an option there to require such an address to be assigned to that interface - and if that doesn't work, you might need to set one yourself, manually.

So when your PC WiFi interface has an IPv4 address, you need to connect to that interface from your phone, using that interface address.

Also, your WiFi network needs to be set to "trusted" in the network settings for that interface, or your firewall might block the connection. Alternatively, with a more rigorous security setting for that interface, you might need to set your firewall to allow such connections. But if you're at home and just starting, then either try simply the "trusted" rule, or turn off the firewall for a few moments - but disconnect from the internet and all other networks before you do. It's best to play around on a testing machine where you don't have data to worry about.

I personally connect the other way around. I create a WiFi hotspot on my phone and connect to that with my PC. On the phone's VNC client, I enter the PC WiFi (IPv4) interface address of the USB dongle to connect to. Also, tigervnc allows not using any passwords or encryption, so for starters I suggest using those options just to get things working and see it actually work. For example, I use a "scraping" VNC server to have my primary and only session also available through VNC:

```
x0tigervncserver -SecurityTypes none -display :0 -localhost no --I-KNOW-THIS-IS-INSECURE
```

So this will run a VNC server that has no security at all, no password and no user name needed as well. The server connects my phone client directly to my standard session on display 0 . But by default, in such a case, tigervnc will only connect local clients - i.e., only VNC clients on the same machine (only on localhost, hence the name local host, because it's only local to the machine itself). Therefore I need to override this feature by using the flags "-localhost no" and "--I-KNOW-THIS-IS-INSECURE". This then makes the VNC server accept connections from the network. All I need to enter in a VNC client is the IPv4 interface address of the machine running the VNC server. (To list running servers use "x0tigervncserver -list". To kill a server run "x0tigervncserver -kill".)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the server's address, and not `localhost` on the client. You can find the server's internal IP address by running

```
hostname -I
```

If there is more than one IP address, try all of them.

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work.